# The negation of neighborhood definition in topological space

Tags: general-topology

From proofwiki, a neighborhood $N_z$ of a point $z$ is $\exists\: U\in \tau:z\in U\subset N_z\subset S$. May I know how to negate the statement? The negation of there exists become for all but how to negate such that?

Thank you!

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Neighborhood_(Topology)

(I am sorry if my question is confusing. I am trying to prove a set is not a neighbourhood around a point b. So that is why I need the definition of not a neighborhood.)

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't make sense as is. If $z \in X$ and the topology is on $X$, there must exist $U \in \tau$ with $x \in U$. You have to understand what "open" means in a general topological space.

A neighborhood is thus a set $V \subset X$ so that there exists a member of the topology with $z \in U \subset V$.

As far as negation goes, this is a set that does not contain an open set around the point. For example[image]

is not a neighborhood because there is no $U$ with $p \in U \subset V$.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write intuitively what the definition says, but the description was going to be just that definition restated. Note that in some contexts, neighborhood is used interchangeably with *open* neighborhood $N_z$ of a point $z$, which is a neighborhood of a point $z$ which is itself open, i.e. $N_z\in \tau$.

So a set which is not a neighborhood of $z$ would be a set $Y$ that contains no open set which contains $z$. I would write this as $\forall\: U\in \tau$, if $U\subset Y$, then $z\not\in U$, though this is not a formal logical negation.

An example: Let $Y=\{0\}\cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\forall z\in Y$, $Y$ is not a neighborhood of $z$, since $\not\exists U\in \tau$ with $U\subset Y$.